# getting started with css in Dreamweaver cs6. Noob issue

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I've just recently downloaded dreamweaver cs6. I've been following tutorials online, and I've run into a bit of a snag. I'm almost embarrassed asking this question, because I know I must be missing something obvious, but here it goes:

I'm following a tutorial right now on making a drop-down menu out of pure CSS. After implementing the first few lines of CSS code I was losing all of my sub menus in the drop-down. After pulling my hair out trying to figure out why for the better part of 2 hours, I finally preview in Firefox.  (can't believe I didn't try earlier.) 
    It all seems to work fine in my browser, but I was wondering: Is there a way I can look at it in Dreamweaver? Its really inconvenient popping in and out of my browser everytime I want to check something.  Like I said, I'm basically (not really basically, I just am) a complete noob at all things web-design. Thank you for your time.

Comment: i think the neatbean ide is more powerful and fast with a good intelligence ...

Comment: @RegisteredUser It doesn't have WYSIWYG! :(

Comment: @PraveenKumar that one the biggest cons of netbean ... we do use it for php and jquery,sql its great

Comment: @RegisteredUser I use it very much for my development! :)

Comment: You can also use http://www.dabblet.com or http://www.jsfiddle.net to preview your code live in the browser.

Comment: Previewing on real browsers is the way to go (ideally, multiple versions of multiple browsers).

Answer (score 2):

Dreamweaver is just an IDE and it is not a browser. It doesn't execute `:hover` events and JavaScripts. You need to preview what you have done using <kbd>F12</kbd> and check it out. :)

Comment: Welcome. There is nothing wrong that you are n00b and this is a silly question. People have issues, they ask here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. At least, there's no reasonable expectation that you should. The problem with web-design is that the only real way to do things properly is to code by hand and preview it in a browser in another window - this does come as a culture-shock to "designers" who are used to WYSIWYG programs like Photoshop and InDesign, but the web is a completely different media where the underlying markup matters the most and is open to re-interpretation by browsers.

Dreamweaver has historically had good WYSIWYG rendering (thanks to their partnership with Opera years ago) but ultimately it's still not the best way.

I note that Microsoft's "Expression Blend for HTML/JS Applications" (there's a mouthful) does actually have first-class design-time WYSIWYG support because it works directly with an instance of IE, so you can test things like `:hover` and client scripts at design time - unfortunately it isn't suited to actual "web" sites - just "desktop" HTML, which is a shame.